# Why do strings load so much slower than numbers?

Tags: javascript, performance, fibonacci

I wrote a script with the purpose of sequencing the Fibonacci Sequence (or any two numbers that would add to make the next, and then those two, etc.). When you press a button, the function (called fibonacci) adds the two values together, pushes the new value into an array (called sequence), and then displays the most recent value in the array. I set it up with a `setInterval` (called recursion), so it continues to add more values to the array, and display more numbers. I was experimenting with the function, and thought to try two strings instead of two numbers. It worked as expected, however it slowed down significantly, crashing the browser within the span of five seconds. I was wondering what the difference would be, performance-wise, between numbers and strings.

My jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/MCBlastoise/yrr7fL4z/54/

And here is my code:

```js
var sequence = [0, 1];
var i = 2;
function recursion() {
 recur = setInterval(fibonacci, 1);
}
function fibonacci() {
 var current = document.getElementById("text");
 var a = sequence[i-2] + sequence[i-1];
 sequence.push(a);
 if (current.innerHTML === "") {
  current.innerHTML = sequence[0] + ", " + sequence[1] + ", " + sequence[2];
 }
 else {
  current.innerHTML = current.innerHTML + ", " + sequence[i];
 }
 i++;
};
function exactValue(position) {
 var current = document.getElementById("text");
 if (isNaN(position) === false && position % 1 === 0 && position >= 1) {
  if (position === 1) {
   current.innerHTML = sequence[0];
  }
  else if (position === 2) {
   current.innerHTML = sequence[1];
  }
  else {
   while (i !== position) {
    var a = sequence[i-2] + sequence[i-1];
    sequence.push(a);
    i++;
   }
   if (i === position) {
    current.innerHTML = "The value at position " + position + " is " + a + ".";
   }
  }
 }
}
function checkValue(value) {
 var current = document.getElementById("text");
 if (isNaN(value) === false) {
  if (value === 0) {
    current.innerHTML = "The value provided appears at position " + 1 + ".";
    }
    else if (value === 1) {
     current.innerHTML = "The value provided appears at position " + 2 + ".";
    }
    else {
   while(a !== value && a !== Infinity) {
    var a = sequence[i-2] + sequence[i-1];
    sequence.push(a);
    i++;
   }
   if (a === value) {
    current.innerHTML = "The value provided appears at position " + i + ".";
      return true;
   }
   if (a === Infinity) {
    current.innerHTML = "The value provided does not appear in  this sequence.";
       return false;
   }
     }
   }
}
function clear() {
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<div onclick="recursion(), clear()" style="cursor:pointer; background-color:black; width:30px; height:30px"></div>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: Nitpick: calling a function at an interval isn't recursion.

Comment: Yeah, I know. To be honest, I just give my functions unique names I'll remember. I named it that cause I read somewhere that the Fibonacci Sequence is called a recursive formula.

Comment: *"...thought to try two strings instead of two numbers"* : where do we see these two strings in your code?

Comment: @trincot Initially, as can be seen in the code, the two values of the 'sequence' array are numbers: `0` and `1`. However, I later tested it with various strings, including `"0"` and `"1"`.

Comment: OK, it was not clear from the question what you actually changed. As Fibonacci is defined for numbers, can you explain what you expect as output from strings? Something like this maybe? `["0", "1", "01", "101", "01101", "10101101", ...]`, or how do you expect the "addition" to work? Can you clarify this as an edit to your question?

Comment: @trincot Yeah, that's exactly what I was expecting. I thought they would concatenate, which they do; what I didn't expect was how much more memory concatenated strings take than bigger numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the elements of the *sequence* array to be strings, the `+` operator in the following line will perform a completely different operation:

```
var a = sequence[i-2] + sequence[i-1];
```

Instead of an arithmetic addition, this will be a string concatenation operation. This will involve a lot more memory and CPU time:

#### Addition of two numbers:

- Time: constant, since an addition is performed as a CPU instruction, limited to the 64-bit float range.
- Memory: one 64-bit float, since that is how numbers are represented in JavaScript.

#### Concatenation of two strings:

- Time: linear in terms of the length of the input strings: each character from both strings needs to be copied to a new memory location
- Memory: doubles, as the final string occupies the same memory as the two input strings together

The memory impact will probably be the factor that kills the script: after only 20 iterations (i.e. calls to *fibonacci*) the string value of *a* will have a length of over 10 000 characters, which will continue to almost double each next iteration. After 30 iterations, *a* will have more than a million characters. If you have enough patience to wait for the string copying of those megabytes to grow to gigabytes you'll find your PC's memory (the part available to the JavaScript box) has been eaten completely, probably before the 40th iteration.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I suspected before I tested it that this might be the case. Out of curiosity, would it take nearly as much memory to simply add the two numbers as usual, and then add them to an empty string, and push that "concatenated" string into the array, like so:                                                                                      `var a = sequence[i-2] + sequence[i-1];`                                 `stringValue = a + ""`                                  `sequence.push(stringValue);`

Comment: You're welcome. The alternative you propose would work well, as the time and space overhead for the string conversion would be limited: the strings will now be the representations of the Fibonacci numbers, not the cumulative concatenation of the original two strings. But then I wonder why you would do that? If you need a string, then postpone that to the last moment: `sequence.push(a); ....... str = sequence.join(', ');`

Comment: I wasn't asking in terms of actual use, since the sequence is based solely in numbers. I was just curious as to the relationship between the two methods, performance-wise. Would what you're suggesting make a significant impact on performance, compared to what I suggested?

Comment: Probably not significant -- converting to strings obviously represents some work. And the use of `join` to concentrate the conversion may only give a slight speed improvement -- if noticeable at all. But it saves some space while building the `sequence` array, as numbers use less space than strings. Why not have a go at it and measure the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Well, loading numbers into memory and adding them can usually be compiled to just a few native CPU instructions, while concatenating Strings usually includes a lot of function calls through the whole language to produce a result. And I'm not sure how JavaScript handles strings internally, but growing a string could mean allocating a whole new byte array for each one.